# Better ways for type casting in C#

Tags: c#, resharper

Case 1: we can convert type by the following ways .....

1. First way

   ```
       int someInt = 10;
       double someDouble = (double) someInt;
   ```
2. Same thing in second way

   ```
       int someInt = 10;
       double someDouble = Convert.ToDouble(someInt);
   ```

Case 2: We can convert somethings into string by the following ways .......

1. First way

   ```
       int someInt = 10;
       string someString =  someInt.ToString();
   ```
2. Second way

   ```
       int someInt = 10;
       string someString =  someInt.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   ```

Now my question is which one is good?? I am asking this question because ReSharper always gives me suggestion like 2nd way for both cases. I don't which one should I follow.

Comment: Second way is good, because Conver.ToDouble(value) can handles null values. If value is null it will not throw exception but in 1st case suppose you write Value.ToString() and if value is null then it will throw exception. And instead of using ToString() , use Convert.ToString().

Comment: @Popeye The `Convert` class isn't the solution to everything.

Comment: You can also use 'as' operator - it will not throw you an exception, only value will be null if conversion fails.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance can you tell me why?

Comment: @Popeye `ToString` is much better when it's called on the class. For example, you can't pass a format string to the `DateTime` overloads. Also, you don't need to worry about null: all of the types that aren't string are value types, and those can't be null. Except string. And calling string.ToString is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Case 1 - both ways are equal, 1st way being little bit faster.
2. Case 2 - 1st way could be dangerous, since `int.ToString()` uses `Culture.CurrentCulture` as an argument (and so results can *vary from computer to computer*):

as in:

```
someInt.ToString() == someInt.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting a variable is just calling the explicit operator method it is syntactic trickery. Casting and Converting through a method are exactly identical or should be. What is different is how the particular class chooses to implement it. You could make a casting operator handle null or not handle null it is up to you.

Consider the following custom class I made. Think about it everything that happens in the casting can be done identically in the method. It is just formatting magic.

```
//explicitly convert int to my class
public static explicit operator MyClass(int t)
{
return new MyClass();
}

//static method to convert int to my class
public static MyClass ToMyClass()
{
return new MyClass();
}
```